# Use Excel Power Query in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net, excel, asp.net-core, powerquery

I have an Excel sheet which has a Power Query. The data source is a SAP HANA DB, located somewhere. The Power Query pulls data from SAP HANA DB and updates the sheet with fresh data.

I want to make an ASP.NET Core Web Application and make use of this Power Query to display results in a Grid. I want to get rid of this Excel.

Is it possible to use this Power Query in ASP.NET as the Data Source ? If yes, how it can be done. Any example will be of help.

**Sample Power Query**

```
let
    Source = SapHana.Database("myserver.net"),
    Contents = Source{[Name="Contents"]}[Data],
    TMP1.SD = Contents{[Name="TMP1.SD"]}[Data],
    TMPV_SalesOrder1 = TMP1.SD.SD{[Name="TMPV_SalesOrder"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(TMPV_SalesOrder1,
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "Batch", {"Batch"}, {"Batch"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "BillingBlockText", {"BillingBlockText"}, {"BillingBlockText"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "BillingDocumentDate", {"BillingDocumentDate"}, {"BillingDocumentDate"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "CreatedByText", {"CreatedByText"}, {"CreatedByText"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "CreatedByUser", {"CreatedByUser"}, {"CreatedByUser"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "CreationDate", {"CreationDate"}, {"CreationDate"}},
             {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "NetAmount", "NetAmount"},
        }),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Items",{"Batch", "BillingBlockText", "BillingDocumentDate", "CreatedByText", "CreatedByUser"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"CreationDate", type date}})
```